# サーバー複数台でのlogin with facebook

Tags: php, aws

現在、AWSで2台サーバーを立てて、ロードバランシングをしているのですが、facebook loginがうまく実装できません。

ログインしようとすると、

Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing.

上記のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

サーバー1台の時はうまくいっていたのですが、、

詳しい方、ご教示ください。よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

OAuthでログインページへリダイレクトする際に、stateをクッキーに入れて管理していると思いますが、保存したサーバと読み出すサーバが異なると発生するかと思います。
セッション情報を複数台のサーバで共有するか、ロードバランサで同一セッションは同一サーバに振り分けられるようにする必要があるかもしれません。